# Consume `index.d.ts` declaration file in source code

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I would like to reuse the type definitions within `index.d.ts` when porting plain `.js` files to `.ts` in my project. However I get `Cannot find name 'Type'`.

I feel like this is some configuration issue I'm banging my head against.
Any help, much appreciated - thanks.

The folder structure looks like this

```sh
<root>
  - /javascript (all js files)
  index.d.ts    (declarations)
```

This is my current tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2017",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": [ "es2017" ],                      /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of all declaration files (*.d.ts). */

    /* Additional Checks */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./javascript",                /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that yields the error.

Comment: Please notice, this is a published JS Lib. People use this in their TS projects. 
I want to convert this from JS to TS itself - just for clarification.

Comment: It should be simply working. It probably has something to do with how the index.d.ts is written or how it's referenced. What library is it?

Answer (score 5):

In a JavaScript project you have to maintain you `index.d.ts` by yourself, but once the project is converted in TypeScript (and `declaration` option is uncommented in your tsconfig.json) `index.d.ts` is produced by tsc. It doesn't sound as a great idea to have a TypeScript project with a self maintained `index.d.ts`.

Probably you simply need to convert your project and maintain the same exported interfaces.

To achieve this you just need to use the same declarations you have now in your `index.d.ts` in your converted TypeScript files too (cut&paste declarations and enrich them with the definitions).

Let's take in exam a simple JavaScript package:

```
function charcatersCount(str) {
  return str.length;
}

module.exports = { charactersCount };
```

the hand maintained `index.d.ts` file will look like:

```
export declare function charactersCount(str: string): number;
```

What I'm suggesting is to open a newly created `index.ts` file, cut&paste the declarations and change them from declarations to definitions

```
export function charactersCount(str: string): number {}
```

finally enrich them with the actual definition:

```
export function charactersCount(str: string): number {
  return str.length;
}
```

reapet this for each exported function/class/constant/variable.

Now running `tsc` with `declaration` option (`--declaration` from command line, or `"declaration": true,` in `tsconfig.json` file) will produce a `index.js` file (the compiled version) and a `index.d.ts` file (the declaration file) more or less identical to the source one.

From now on you'll no longer need to maintain your `index.d.ts` file by hands: every time you change your package `tsc` will produce it.

While about the specific error `Cannot find name 'Type'`, I need to see the code producing it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you maybe reword your answer, I don't get it. 

> To achieve this you just need to use the same declarations you have now in your index.d.ts in your converted TypeScript files too (cut&paste declarations and enrich them with the definitions).

So I have to copy paste the types I already set up in `index.d.ts` into the TS files or a `types` files folder to use them in my new JS -> TS source files?

Why can't I just utilize the already set up `index.d.ts`, this seems shortsighted...

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer - so in short, I can't re-utilize the already created `index.d.ts` file. 
I'll try your recommended approach and report back with the results. 

`Cannot find name 'Type'` then probably comes, because it can't find the types from the current `index.d.ts`...

Comment: You actually could, but IMHO it's not a good idea. About the error, it could be as you supposed, but I'm pretty sure that doing things well it simply won't happen.

Comment: I really feel like this should be the accepted answer. You said that you're porting plain `.js` to `.ts`. So, it only makes sense to port everything you have in your `.d.ts` to the newly created `.ts` files and merge with your js code. The only reason why you might want to have this `.d.ts` is because you're converting only some js files. In this case, you might want to use namespaces to merge your generated `.d.ts` and manually maintained one.

Comment: I don't know why but be too really feel like this should be the accepted answer. :D Apart from jokes, thank you @MaximMazurok

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a collision in your module resolution.

If you have a file called `index.ts`, then `index.d.ts` won't be automatically imported.

TypeScript will automatically import .d.ts files, UNLESS their name collides with other files, where the rules for what files will collide are somewhat described here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html .

> So import { b } from "moduleB" in source file /root/src/moduleA.ts would result in the following lookups:
>
> ````
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.tsx
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB.d.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "types" property)
> /root/src/node_modules/@types/moduleB.d.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.ts
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.tsx
> /root/src/node_modules/moduleB/index.d.ts```
> ````

The solution is to rename your `index.d.ts` file to something else, I recommend the name of your project (as long as there isn't also a `.ts` file that will collide with that name!).